# How can I pass arguments to the python interpreter like "-u" in launch.json configurations?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to call `python -u file.py` in VS Code debug mode. I get that I can use the `"args"` field to specify arguments, but what about python interpreter flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `"type": "python"` in your launch configuration, just use the `"pythonArgs"` field and pass an array of arguments (as strings) to pass to the python interpreter.

That field's description:

> Command-line arguments passed to the Python interpreter. To pass arguments to the debug target, use "args".

For example:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "pythonArgs": ["-u"]
        }
    ]
}
```